# /wp-admin/ working but no other permalinks are working due to .htaccess setup confusion

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, permalinks

I need to redirect the homepage to index.html and /business to /business/index.html so I've modified the rewrite rules written in by WordPress by default:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^business/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If I remove my rules permalinks work again but I really need these rules in... /wp-admin still works just fine.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to mess with `.htaccess` rewrite rules?

You can simply use this on the the default wordpress `php` page:

```
Header('Location: index.html');
```

Comment: No clue haha. I just assumed that was the best way to do it. Thanks.